# Existe um pacote serviços no padrão MVC?

Tags: mvc

Existe um pacote de serviços no padrão MVC? Seria um MVCS?

Por exemplo, tenho uma classe ConnectionFactory - que serve para conectar ao banco de dados. Isso seria uma serviço. Onde coloco isso no padrão MVC? Seria no pacote Controlador ou criaria um novo pacote chamado Servicos?

Outra dúvida: e as exceções, em que pacote coloco?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geralmente este tipo de serviço fica em uma pasta chamada config, ou app->config. As exceções, que ao meu ver seria arquivos de um framework por exemplo, ficária em vendor.

Esse tipo de modelo é muito utilizado por frameworks, como Zend e Laravel (Frameworks PHP).

Estrutura de pasta do Zend:

```
-config
     -autoload
-data
     -cache
-module
     -Application
-public
     -css
     -js
     -image
-vendor
     -zendframework
     -bin
```

Sendo que a pasta config fica responsável pelos arquivos de configuração de toda aplicação. A pasta data, para os arquivos salvos na aplicação. Module fica com os arquivos responsável pelo mvc de cada modulo da aplicação. Public é a pasta responsavel pelos aquivos publicos, muito desses arquivos utilizados nas views. E vendor, onde fica o framework e váriados.